# Adding a list to a combobox while checking if the object already exists

Tags: c#, list, combobox, boolean

I'm relatively new to programming so please excuse me for asking such simple questions haha.
Well, basically I have groupnames that can be made by the user. Group is a class with the field "string NameGroup". The groupnames are filled in a textbox and are being saved here:

```
List<Group> Groups = new List<Group>();
```

What I want to do is check whether a groupname already exists before adding it to the list but it doesn't seem to work for some reason. I tried 2 different bools:

```
bool Check= Groups.ToString().Contains(txtNewGroup.Text);
bool containsItem = Groups.Any(item => txtNewGroup.Text == item.NameGroup.ToString());
```

The first one doesn't work at all and the second one gives me an error after entering the same groupname in the textbox.

After having checked whether the groupname exists, I want to add it to the combobox but this doesn't seem to work either.

```
if (containsItem == false)
{

    Groups.Add(new Group(txtNewGroup.Text));
    txtNewGroup.Clear();

}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Groupname isn't available, try something else");
    txtNewGroup.Clear();
}

cbxGroups.DataSource = Groups.ToString();
```

This is the class Group:

```
    class Group
{
    //Fields
    private string nameGroup;


    //Properties
    public string NameGroup
    {
        get;
        set;
    }



    //Constructor
    public Group(string name)
    {
        this.nameGroup = name;

    }
 }
```

So, my questions are:
1. What's wrong with either of my bools?
2. Why does it not add the contents of the list into the combobox?

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: The first one doesn't give any errors but doesn't work either.

Comment: The second one: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
bool Check= Groups.ToString().Contains(txtNewGroup.Text);
```

Since `Groups` is a `List`, although your group contain `string`, this will not be correct since it will just return the `List` type `ToString`.

Also, when you say `Contains(txtNewGroup.Text)` this should be rather pointing to the `string` in the `Group` class then the `Group` class itself, otherwise it is almost likely to be wrong (unless `Group` itself is a `string`)

So, assuming you have `Group` class like this (in my program, it is named `DummyClass` - since I do not know what is your `Group` like)

```
public class DummyClass {
    public int DummyInt;
    public string DummyString; //note this string!
    public double DummyDouble;
    public DummyClass() {

    }
    public DummyClass(int dummyInt, string dummyString, double dummyDouble) {
        DummyInt = dummyInt;
        DummyString = dummyString;
        DummyDouble = dummyDouble;
    }
}
```

And initialized it as

```
DummyClass dc1 = new DummyClass(1, "This dummy", 2.0);
DummyClass dc2 = new DummyClass(2, "That dummy", 2.0);
DummyClass dc3 = new DummyClass(1, "These dummies", 2.0);
DummyClass dc4 = new DummyClass(2, "Those dummies", 2.0);
DummyClass dc5 = new DummyClass(3, "The dummies", 2.0);
List<DummyClass> dummyList = new List<DummyClass>() { dc1, dc2, dc3, dc4, dc5 };
```

You should rather check directly from the `Groups` using `LINQ` like what I did to the `dummyList`

```
if (!dummyList.Select(x => x.DummyString).Contains("dummies")) {
    //This is new item without dummies!
}
```

Likewise yours should be like

```
bool Check = Groups.Select(g => g.NameGroup).Contains(txtNewGroup.Text);
```

This way you really check if there is any `Group` in your `Groups` whose `StringMember` already is the same as the `txtNewGroup.Text`

Edit:

There is another problem with your `Group` property.

```
class Group
{
    //Fields
    private string nameGroup;

    //Properties
    public string NameGroup
    {
        get; //There is nothing in the property, and it is never used either!
        set;
    }

    //Constructor
    public Group(string name)
    {
        this.nameGroup = name; //this means the field is updated    
    }
 }
```

Which causes the `name` only saved in the `nameGroup` but not in the `NameGroup`. Thus when `NameGroup` is called outside of this class, it always gives nothing. Change the above class into:

```
class Group
{
    //Fields
    private string nameGroup;

    //Properties
    public string NameGroup
    {
        get {return nameGroup;} //this way, your nameGroup and NameGroup are one
        set {nameGroup = value;}
    }

    //Constructor
    public Group(string name)
    {
        this.nameGroup = name; //this means the field is updated    
    }
 }
```

This way, your `nameGroup` and `NameGroup` are one. Alternatively, if you don't need the field at all, you can just remove it

```
class Group
{
    //Properties
    public string NameGroup { get; set; }

    //Constructor
    public Group(string name)
    {
        this.NameGroup = name; //use the property directly
    }
 }
```

And it should work

Comment: I changed the bool as you advised but it still doesn't work.         Groups.Select(Group => Group.NameGroup).Contains(txtNewGroup.Text)

Comment: @AniBankai I edited my answer. See also my comments.

Comment: I changed it accordingly but it still doesn't save the names to the list.    bool Checks = Groups.Select(group => group.NameGroup).Contains(txtNewGroup.Text);

Comment: Seems like the problem lies somewhere else. In that case, perhaps you can try to update what you get when you implement the method above first? Also, please post how you save the name in the first place. And if possible, show what is the `Group` class too.

Comment: I save the name in the string field of class Group. I added the class in the post.

Comment: @AniBankai Ok, great. I spotted the issue. Kindly check it.

Comment: I'm such an idiot for forgetting to fill in that piece. It works like a charm when I leave out the part of it adding the list to the combobox. However, when I add the code where it adds the list to the combobox I get an error after filling in the groupname: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: The saving to the list works now. However, adding the list to the combobox gives an error.

Comment: @AniBankai Ok, great! So we know the issue. ;) the argument exception must belong to another issue. I would be better if you post a separate post regarding that (if necessary). Because it is not good in SO to post all chunks of issues together in a single post.

Comment: @AniBankai but as long as you use search in SO forum, I think such issue is a lot more common than issue you posted on this. You would get the answer easily even without posting another post. ;)

Comment: True. Thanks a bunch for the help!